# How can i treat functions like objects in ruby?

Tags: ruby

In my ruby project, i want to create a task manager class which will periodically iterate through an array of registered functions. I need to pass functions as argument to the register function, create a thread and when the thread timer fires, it needs to call each function in array.

```
class TaskMan

    @@func_array = Array.new

    def self.register_func &arg_func
        @@func_array.push arg_func
    end

    def self.run_server
        loop do
            @@func_array.each do |func|
                func.call
            end
            sleep 60 
        end
    end

end

class Callee

    def self.func_0
       puts "func_0 called."
    end

    def self.func_1
        puts "func_1 called."
    end

end

TaskMan.register_func Callee.func_0
TaskMan.register_func Callee.func_1

taskman_thread = Thread.new do
    TaskMan.run_server
end
taskman_thread.join
```

Basically, this is what i want to do, but i'm not sure how to use `to_proc` and `call`, to push in the functions and call them.

Other solutions are also appreciated, but i don't want to avoid learning passing functions as arguments, putting them in array and calling them.

Thanks.

Comment: Ruby doesn't have functions. Your question is unclear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can instead pass the receiver and the function you intend calling as below:

```
class TaskMan

  @@func_array = Array.new

  def self.register_func(receiver, func)
    @@func_array.push([receiver, func])
  end

  def self.run_server
    loop do
      @@func_array.each do |(receiver, func)|
        receiver.method(func).call
      end
      sleep 60
    end
  end

end

class Callee

  def self.func_0
    puts "func_0 called."
  end

  def self.func_1
    puts "func_1 called."
  end

end

TaskMan.register_func Callee, :func_0
TaskMan.register_func Callee, :func_1

taskman_thread = Thread.new do
  TaskMan.run_server
end
taskman_thread.join
```

Answer (score 2):

Use the [`method` method](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Object.html#method-i-method) to get the class methods as callable objects (`Method` instances in this case) and then apply `&` to those objects:

```
TaskMan.register_func &Callee.method(:func_0)
TaskMan.register_func &Callee.method(:func_1)
```

Now you can throw all sorts of things into the `func_array`:

```
TaskMan.register_func &SomeClass.method(:m)   # class method
TaskMan.register_func &some_object.method(:m) # an instance method
TaskMan.register_func &some_lambda            # a lambda function
TaskMan.register_func { puts "pancakes" }     # a block
# etc.
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's say you have methods `func_0` and `func_1`. To call them using array iteration you can do this

```
methods = [:func_0, :func_1]
methods.each do |m|
  send(m)
end
```

Comment: you can't just call `send(m)` in the OP's example the receiver of the function is not `self` in his case